# Is there a way to get Material MainTexture name?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate a plane that has a VideoPlayer component that sends a video to the MainTexture of the material of this same plane. 
I get the video from an URL and put "Material Override" as my Render Mode.

The problem is: I have to adjust the plane size according to the aspect ratio of the video (the width always has to be the same, so I have to adjust just the height).

I can access the material of my plane, but when I try to access the Main Texture it returns null. I just need the size of this Main Texture (which I believe is a temporary RenderTexture, created by unity, that has the exact same size as the Video resolution) so I can get the ratio to scale my plane.

I have to do this by script because the player has to select the video from his computer, so it has to work with any video the player chooses.

If anyone knows another way to get the video resolution from the Video Player (remembering the video comes from an URL, so it's not an VideoClip), I can give it a try too.

Comment: You can try accesing the texture via videoPlayer.texture, or simply, instead of using MaterialOverride, override the material by hand

Comment: @zambari when I put videoPlayer.texture it also returns null... By override the material by hand you mean, like, creating a RenderTexture, putting the video on it and then putting the RenderTexture on the plane material? If yes, i've tried to do this but when I create a RenderTexture myself it has a static size that doesn't change no matter the video resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just found out that I have to check if the VideoPlayer is prepared before get any information from its texture. That solved the error.